# Automate Database backup in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, database-backups

I am looking for a solution - a script to automate the process of taking backup of a database in PostgreSQL. As of now I do it manually, that is by right clicking on the db and clicking the backup option. 
I did some research and ended up with a script which solves the issue pretty much, ie:

```
@ECHO OFF
@setlocal enableextensions
@cd /d "%~dp0"

SET PGPATH=C:\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\
SET SVPATH=d:\
SET PRJDB=Test
SET DBUSR=postgres
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%i IN ('DATE /T') DO SET d=%%i-%%j-%%k
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2,3 DELIMS=: " %%i IN ('TIME /T') DO SET t=%%i%%j%%k

SET pg_dump=%PRJDB%_%d%_%t%.backup
@ECHO OFF
%PGPATH%pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres %PRJDB% > %SVPATH%%pg_dump%

echo Backup Taken Complete %SVPATH%%pg_dump%
pause
```

It did take the backup, but the file generated was a sql file, though I did change the extension to `.backup`. As a result, if I need to restore the DB, and try to restore from the file generated it is not possible. Can someone please provide me with a solution to this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you just want automate postgresql backup like scheduling the backup or what ??

Comment: Yes, schedule a process to take the backup.

Comment: _It did take the backup, but the file generated was a sql file, though i did change the extension to .backup. As a result, if i need to restore the DB, and try to restore from the file generated it is not possible_ dont you need a solution for this ??

Comment: and when comes to scheduling you  can simply use windows `Schedule Task `, here is an example http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7

Comment: Yes, See i found this script which helps me to automate a backup which includes the process of Taskscheduling and other stuff. As of now my problem is that i am not able to generate a ".backup" file, all i can do is a ".sql" file.

Comment: Try this - http://hastebin.com/ajocisifep.dos

Comment: Just wondering: Why is *.sql not suitable as it is some kind of backup? What do you want to achieve and why didn't you post this question on  http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: When we create a sql backup, and then try to restore the same in PostgreSql , it doesnt support it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following script can be used to get the Postgres backup with `.backup` extension

```
 @echo off
       for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
         set dow=%%i
         set month=%%j
         set day=%%k
         set year=%%l
       )
       set datestr=%day%_%month%_%year%
       echo datestr is %datestr%

       set BACKUP_FILE=C:\Users\slan\Desktop\backup_test\DBNAME_%datestr%.backup
       echo backup file name is %BACKUP_FILE%
       SET PGPASSWORD=YOUR_PASSWORD
       echo on
       bin\pg_dump -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% YOUR_DB_NAME
```

---

you must have PostgreSQL's bin folder(Ex. `C:\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin`) along with this script otherwise this will not work as you expect

To schedule the task you can use Windows Task scheduler, here is an example for how to ?? - [How to schedule a Batch File to run automatically in Windows 10 / 8 / 7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7)

Comment: No.. its not the DB name.. its the path where the batch file and the bin is stored!!

Comment: Hello, i tried execute this in pgAdmin query but it encountered error:     `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
LINE 1:    @echo off`

whats wrong with the script?

Comment: @fLen It is a batch script(`.bat`) DOS commands not a SQL/PLSQL commands

Answer (score 1):

You can use PGagent for scheduling batch it have multiple advantages over windows scheduler bat scripts